# select option from dropdown using API and get that selected value but i am getting last value which i have not selected in react

Tags: reactjs

I am not getting my selected value from dropdown

```
    <select className={Styles.formControl} style={{ width: '580px'}} name="relationship"  id="relationship" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur}>
     {data?.map((option, index) => (
        <option key={`options_key_${index}`} selected={option.value !== userObject?.relationship}>{option.relationship}</option> 
        ))} 
    </select>
```

Comment: Please share your `onChange` and `onBlur` functions in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select className={Styles.formControl} style={{ width: '580px'}} name="relationship"  id="relationship" onChange={handleChange} onBlur={handleBlur}>
                                            {data?.map((option, index) => (
                                                <option key={`options_key_${index}`} selected={option.relationship === userObject?.relationship}>{option.relationship}</option> 
                                           ))} 
                                        </select>
```

I think this will work.

Comment: thanks sir for helping me